# Unable to connect to PostgreSQL through KETTLE-Pentaho

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, postgresql-9.1, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have pasted below the snippets of Kettle DB Connection Configuration and of PgAdmin PostgreSQL Dashboard.

Please advice what I am doing wrong.

Localhost and Password are right.

Kettle configuration:

[image: Kettle Configuration]

Snippet of PGADMIN dashboard

[image: Snippet of PGADMIN dashboard]

The error message is:

```
Error connecting to database [Postgre_Ady] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error occurred while trying to connect to the database Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver) Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
```

Below pasted is  pg_hba.conf file

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# plain TCP/IP socket.
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (between 0 and 32 (IPv4) or 128 (IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives
# a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have
# to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can
# use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.

# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.



# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: And what is the error message? Are you **really** running Postgres on port 10892? The default port is 5432

Comment: You'll have to provide more data: What is the error message, what was the `CREATE DATABASE` statement, what are the relevant lines from `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Error connecting to database [Postgre_Ady] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Comment: Hi, DB Create Script is pasted below, 
CREATE DATABASE "Ady"
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

Comment: The error message indicates that you are indeed using the wrong port in Kettle (Postgres must be running otherwise you couldn't connect through pgAdmin). This is defined in `postgresql.conf`, not in `pg_hba.conf`. Use `show port` to see the listening port. **That** is the value you need to enter in the Kettle input field, not some random integer value.

Answer (score 1):

This how to get server IP and Port  (If u use pgadmin4 means it is recent version of postgres and those functions already available)

```
select inet_server_addr(),      inet_server_port()
```

According to screenshot, value "10892" is pid (process id) not a port number.

Default port number as mention @jipipayo is 5432

Answer (score 0):

as user @a_horse_with_no_name pointed , the postgresql server listening port is wrong.

change the port number to **5432** on your kettle config, this is the default listening port on postgresql servers